# Crossword: split a string of letters into valid words from a dictionary

Tags: regex, perl, dictionary, crossword

Given:

1. A phrase with the spaces removed and converted to lower case - e.g. "ashotinthearm" from "a shot in the arm";
2. A dictionary which returns true or false if a word exists ("a", "as", "ash", "shot", "hot", etc., would all return true)

What is an efficient method to find the individual words which, when glued together with spaces, make up that phrase?

There may be more than one solution, even if some are gibberish:

- ashotinthearm (a shot in the arm, as hot in the arm)
- asintended (as intended, as in tended)
- brothersinlaw (brothers in law, brother sin law)
- guysanddolls (guys and dolls, guy sand dolls)
- haveascrewloose (have a screw loose, have as crew loose)
- ifeelthepinch (I feel the pinch, if eel the pinch)
- isinyourcourt (is in your court, I sin your court)
- manorhouse (manor house, man or house)
- manormouse (man or mouse, manor mouse)
- newzealand (New Zealand, new zeal and)
- oneatatime (one at a time, on eat a time)
- portableradio (portable radio, port able radio)
- scotspine (scots pine, scot spine)
- shopsoiled (shop soiled, shops oiled)

Would ideally prefer a PERL and/or regex solution, but grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: This would be hard to do. Where to place regex emphasis ..

Comment: Isn't there a linux command that does something like this? It finds anagrams out of sentences or words, which is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this recursive solution?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wW

use strict;

#global "constants"
my @words=("a", "as", "ash", "shot", "hot", "in", "the", "arm");
my %wordsHash = map { $_ => 1 } @words;

sub getParts($@);
sub dictionary($);

# returns true if in dict
sub dictionary($) {
    my ($str) = @_;
    return(defined($wordsHash{$str}));
}

# recursive function
sub getParts($@) {
    my ($phrase, @priorWords) = @_ ;
    print "DEBUG: step prior words(" . join(" ", @priorWords) . ") phrase($phrase) \n";

    #recursion end:
    if(!$phrase) {
        print "solution:" . join(" ", @priorWords) . "\n";
        return;
    }
    for my $i (1 .. length($phrase) ) {
        my $word = substr($phrase,0,$i);
        if(dictionary($word)) {
            getParts(substr($phrase,$i),(@priorWords,$word));
        }
    }
}

getParts("ashotinthearm", () );
```

Output is:

```
DEBUG: step prior words() phrase(ashotinthearm) 
DEBUG: step prior words(a) phrase(shotinthearm) 
DEBUG: step prior words(a shot) phrase(inthearm) 
DEBUG: step prior words(a shot in) phrase(thearm) 
DEBUG: step prior words(a shot in the) phrase(arm) 
DEBUG: step prior words(a shot in the a) phrase(rm) 
DEBUG: step prior words(a shot in the arm) phrase() 
solution:a shot in the arm
DEBUG: step prior words(as) phrase(hotinthearm) 
DEBUG: step prior words(as hot) phrase(inthearm) 
DEBUG: step prior words(as hot in) phrase(thearm) 
DEBUG: step prior words(as hot in the) phrase(arm) 
DEBUG: step prior words(as hot in the a) phrase(rm) 
DEBUG: step prior words(as hot in the arm) phrase() 
solution:as hot in the arm
DEBUG: step prior words(ash) phrase(otinthearm)
```

Comment: Don't use [prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) unless you know what they are for. Which is to emulate the non-standard behaviour of some Perl built-in functions.

Comment: Many thanks to RobbySherwood for his elegant solution. The key insight was to use recursion.

The code as given works perfectly. TLP correctly points out some oddities regarding prototypes; perhaps RobbySherwood comes from a C background ?

A couple of trivial changes - mere nitpicking - to make it more "perlish" might include


    `if (length($phrase)==0) -> if (!$phrase) 

    for (my $i=1; $i<=length($phrase); $i++) -> for my $i (1 .. length($phrase))

    the final "return" in getParts isn't needed`
 

(I couldn't work out how to show the above on separate lines ...)

Comment: YES! C background... :-)

Comment: I still don't see how the prototypes are "unperlish" (?) - i think, declaration and compile-time parameter check is a big help to keep overview and avoid strange bugs or effects... do i miss a good and more perlish alternative?